# how to make text centered under top-border

Tags: css

I have a CSS horizontal Menu that has a top-border and text underneath it.

i need to get the text under the top-border in the center of the border line:

```
#topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
#topbar-inner {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#logo {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#menu {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
/*    border-top:4px solid #666666; */
    margin-right:20px;
   /* padding-top:20px; */
    min-width:120px;
}
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    /* margin-top:25px; */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#menu > li:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#menu li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-top:25px;   
    border-top:4px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#menu li a:hover { 
    border-color:#FFFFFF; 
    color:#fff
}
```

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/y75WZ/

any ideas what i can do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`text-align:center` for the `li` or the `a` tag inside `li` should do it.

```
#menu li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-top:25px;   
    border-top:4px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

or

```
#menu li {
     text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

... Do you mean `text-align:center` on the list items?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y75WZ/1/

Use a simple `text-align: center;`.

```
#menu li a {
    text-align: center;
    /* ... */
}
```

---

Btw. what were you trying here:

`#menu` doesn't have any direct descendants which are `li`.

```
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    /* margin-top:25px; */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#menu > li:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below css

```
#menu li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-top:25px;   
    border-top:4px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I just changed your code and below is the new fiddle which is a modified version of your code.
Check below fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/y75WZ/3/